# How to pass javascript value to flask for face detection website?

Tags: flask, image-processing, computer-vision, face-recognition, face-detection

I got 405 HTTP code status, after I add `methods=["POST"]`

I'm making web with face detection feature.
I tried to pass boolean value from javascript to my function `generate_frames()` that is inside `Response()`.

This generate_frames function contains a face detection code. If status True, then bounding box is shown, if it's False then the bounding box is not shown.

```
@app.route("/video", methods=["POST"])
def video():
    status = request.get_json()["effect_status"]
    print(status)
    return Response(
        generate_frames(status=status),
        mimetype="multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame",
    )
```

However I got, 405 HTTP code, and my web isn't showing anything.